# Converting HTML/CSS/JS site to React App with tailwind css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i have a site template with its html, css, and all assets needed , and i need to build a react js application with this template.

My first question is :

- knowing that i use tailwind css for all my other projects, is it a better approach to use it in this case or i should just put all the css files from the template in my react application folder and import them in my components then convert the html files into react component ?

My second question is :

- If using tailwind css is better is ther an approach to follow to convert all the css and html into react components styles with tailwind css ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be

Answer 1

If you already have css ready, you could just `import` them in your components, and any further changes could be done using `tailwind-css` .

Answer 2

If you are particular about the whole application to have only `tailwind classes` then you can convert your `css classes` into `tailwind-css classes` using https://tailwind-converter.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

Adding another tool for the second question. You can use [DivMagic](https://divmagic.com) which lets you convert all CSS and HTML into React components with Tailwind CSS classes with one click.

Note: I built this tool